# size of the tabBarItems in a UITabBarController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitabbarcontroller

I have 4 tabs in my APP for `iPad`. The problem is that sometimes the text is bigger than the button but i have more space to use. However, the `UITabBarController` doesn't use all the width for the `tabBarItems`. Is there an option to do it?

Comment: Are you talking about UITab**Bar**Controller and UITab**Bar**Button ?

Comment: Sorry, about UITabBarController. The problem is with the tabBarItems

Answer (score 1):

UITabBarController will automatically insert spaces in between. You could do two things

1. Override UITabButton's sizeThatFits method to give it your own size
2. Insert negative-width spaces in between

For option 2, here's some sample code I used for toolbars of UINavigationBar (and should be applicable to UITabBarController as well)

```
UIBarButtonItem *space = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:self action:nil];
space.width = -10;

[self setToolbarItems:[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:tab_item1,space,tab_item2, nil] animated:NO];
```

I'd suggest to use one space item to the left, one space item to the right and a space item for between of each tab buttons.

Comment: 1. `UITabBarItem` is inherited from `NSObject` and has no `sizeThatFits` method 2. You cannot init `UITabBarController` with the custom array of objects :(

Comment: Look at UITabButton, not UITabBarItem

Comment: There is no class `UITabButton`

Comment: You're right. Sorry I don't remember (answer from long while ago).