# tab bar item text gets compressed if text greater than 5 alphabets

Tags: ios, swift, ios8, uitabbaritem

I have set a custom font to tab bar item with text greater than 5 alphabets.
The space between alphabets gets removed and text shrinks horizontally.
How to keep text spacing intact.
This issue is same as 
[Title text hugging/kerning + clipping in UITabBarItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27064138/title-text-hugging-kerning-clipping-in-uitabbaritem)

Comment: use custom tab bar, because you cannot implement multiline text if it is huge

Comment: customize the tab bar item image and text accordingly in storyboard. It can be done there itself.

Comment: yes image can be used but i forgot one thing to tell that I wanted to use badge in that tabbar item and if I use image it shifts at the end of image top so I used image and text separately